# Tools for data collection

Tags: database, data-analysis, microsoft-excel

Lets say you want to collect several datas from branch office. The data will be analyzed to evaluate the monthly performance. What is the best way to collect the datas? Currently I'm using excel template.

Comment: we need more info. Tell us more about where the data are and how you collect them. We need technical info if you want a technical reply

Comment: It would be useful to know what are the issues and bothlenecks you are facing with the current approach. If you don't have any, then the easiest way is to keep doing what you are doing!